# Hacer una animación de contador

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, bootstrap

Tengo un banner donde coloco los años de la empresa entre otras cosas, mi duda es como hacer para que se mueva como un contador. ¿Qué complementos utilizan?

> Este es mi código donde quiero aplicar la animación de contador.

```html
<div class="spacer feature24 spacer bg-light team4">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-7 text-center">
                <h2 class="title font-light">¿Buscas una solución? Te vamos a acompañar en este recorrido</h2>
                <h6 class="subtitle">Ofreciéndote la mejor solución que se adapte a tus necesidades.</h6>
                <div class="m-t-40">
                    <a class="btn btn-outline-inverse btn-rounded btn-md btn-arrow m-t-20" href="https://syntaxtecnologias.com.mx/index.php/Inicio_controller/servicios"><span>Ver servicios<i class="fa fa-arrow-right"></i></span></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Row -->
        <div class="row m-t-30 p-t-30 client-box">
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-smile-o fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">284</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Clientes Felices</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-coffee fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">20</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Años de experiencia</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
            <!-- column  -->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6" style="text-align: center;">
                <div class="no-block contador">
                    <i class="fa fa-users fa-3x"></i>
                    <div class="m-l-20">
                        <h3 class="font-light counter m-b-0">25</h3>
                        <h6 class="text-muted font-13 text-uppercase">Personal especializado</h6>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- column  -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');
  
  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },
  {
    duration: 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
      //alert('finished');
    }

  });  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color:#fff;
  max-width:800px;
  margin: 100px auto 0;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin:1.5%;
  font-size:50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width:200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height:200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
```

Podrías usar algo como esto. A través de la función `animate()` y usando un atributo `data` de **HTML5** podrías generar un listado rápido de los números comprendidos entre 0 y lo que definas en el atributo `data`.

**Referencia:** [Ejemplo](https://codepen.io/hi-im-si/pen/uhxFn)